# Import module from subpackage in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

i know it's a faq but i cant figure out how to call a module from a subpackage into another subpackage.

This is the [file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9cIY.png). I receive [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgGlW.png) when trying to import the module.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use relative paths: from ..pack1.file1 import xxx

Comment: If you make a package containing both of these subpackages installable, you won't have any trouble importing one from the other.

You can do this by writing a setup.py file, see https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html.

Comment: @S4eed3sm i've already tried it but it doesn't work. Says parent module not found

Comment: How you run the program ?